# ChartJs shows the wrong labels

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

First of all, I would like to say that I'm a student learning programming for around a month, so expect to see many mistakes.

I'm working on a website where I use a chart from the ChartJs library. I have one outer circle that shows the hours worked on the company and the hours left to reach the monthly goal. The inner circle shows the days of the month and the days left of the month. Here is the code:

```
const data = {
    labels: ['Summe', 'Noch um Ziel zu erreichen', 'Tage', 'Verbleibende Tage im Monat'],
    datasets: [
      {
        backgroundColor: ['#5ce1e6', '#2acaea'],
        data: [studenGesamt, (800 - studenGesamt)]
      },
      {
        backgroundColor: ['#cd1076', '#8b0a50'],
        data: [dayD, (23 - dayD)]
      },
  
    ]
  };

// Configuration of the pie chart
let outterChart = new Chart(chart, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: data,
    options: {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        labels: {
          generateLabels: function(chart) {
            // Get the default label list
            const original = Chart.overrides.pie.plugins.legend.labels.generateLabels;
            const labelsOriginal = original.call(this, chart);

            // Build an array of colors used in the datasets of the chart
            var datasetColors = chart.data.datasets.map(function(e) {
              return e.backgroundColor;
            });
            datasetColors = datasetColors.flat();

            // Modify the color and hide state of each label
            labelsOriginal.forEach(label => {

              // Change the color to match the dataset
              label.fillStyle = datasetColors[label.index];
            });

            return labelsOriginal;
          }
        },
        onClick: function(mouseEvent, legendItem, legend) {
          // toggle the visibility of the dataset from what it currently is
          legend.chart.getDatasetMeta(
            legendItem.datasetIndex
          ).hidden = legend.chart.isDatasetVisible(legendItem.datasetIndex);
          legend.chart.update();
        }
      },
       tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
          label: function(context) {
            const labelIndex = (context.datasetIndex * 2) + context.dataIndex;
            return context.chart.data.labels[labelIndex] + ': ' + context.formattedValue;
          }
        }
      },
    }
  },
});
```

The completed part of the outer circle should show the label "Summe: X" when you hover it, and the not completed part of the outer circle should show "Noch um Ziel zu erreichen: X", and it works fine. The completed part of the inner circle should show "Tage: X" and the not-completed part of the inner circle should show "Verbleibende Tage im Monat: X" when you hover it, however, it does not.

I had finished this chart last week and it worked fine, showing the labels as I explained above, but when I opened it today, it wasn't showing the labels on that way anymore. I did do some changes but I reverted all of them, as far as I know.

These are some pictures of the chart and its behavior:

[image: Chart]

[image: Correct label]

[image: Wrong label]

On the last picture, the label should say "Tage: 6". The data is correct, but the label text is not. This happens as well on the not completed part of the iner circle, where the data is correct but it shows the same label as the not completed part of the outer circle ("Noch um Ziel zu erreichen" instead of "Verbleibende Tage im Monat"). As I said, this code was working properly last week, so I'm not sure what happened and I can't figure it out. If someone could help me I would really appreciate it, thanks for reading!

Note: The data I'm using for the charts is being taken through requests to a server which contains a JSON file with the information, and then stored in different variables like "stundenGesamt" and "dayD".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you had was that your `tooltip` config was wrong, in v3 the naming was changed from `tooltips` to `tooltip` if you change that it works fine:

```js
const data = {
  labels: ['Summe', 'Noch um Ziel zu erreichen', 'Tage', 'Verbleibende Tage im Monat'],
  datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: ['#5ce1e6', '#2acaea'],
      data: [200, (800 - 200)]
    },
    {
      backgroundColor: ['#cd1076', '#8b0a50'],
      data: [4, (23 - 4)]
    },

  ]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');

// Configuration of the pie chart
let outterChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: data,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        labels: {
          generateLabels: function(chart) {
            // Get the default label list
            const original = Chart.overrides.pie.plugins.legend.labels.generateLabels;
            const labelsOriginal = original.call(this, chart);

            // Build an array of colors used in the datasets of the chart
            var datasetColors = chart.data.datasets.map(function(e) {
              return e.backgroundColor;
            });
            datasetColors = datasetColors.flat();

            // Modify the color and hide state of each label
            labelsOriginal.forEach(label => {

              // Change the color to match the dataset
              label.fillStyle = datasetColors[label.index];
            });

            return labelsOriginal;
          }
        },
        onClick: function(mouseEvent, legendItem, legend) {
          // toggle the visibility of the dataset from what it currently is
          legend.chart.getDatasetMeta(
            legendItem.datasetIndex
          ).hidden = legend.chart.isDatasetVisible(legendItem.datasetIndex);
          legend.chart.update();
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: function(context) {
            const labelIndex = (context.datasetIndex * 2) + context.dataIndex;
            return context.chart.data.labels[labelIndex] + ': ' + context.formattedValue;
          }
        }
      },
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```